# How to upgrade a certain function from AngularJS to Angular 6 or higher?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am currently upgrading our system from AngularJS to Angular 6.

And I cross upon a certain function that uses *.then* like this:

```
searchService.searchSubject(subjectId)
 .then(function(subject) {
        if(subject && subject.length > 0){
            //code block;
        } else {
            //code block;
        }
    })
.catch(function(error) {
        //code block;
    });
}
```

How do I change this function to Angular 6?

Comment: Has nothing special to do with angularjs. That's a Promise, standard javacript. You may refactor into observables to make it more 'angular-like' but that's your choice. The code works

Comment: This code is from a AngularJS project. I want to update this function so it will be used in Angular 6. So, this code works too in Angular 6 as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really you should use flat arrow sintax

```
//include "this" -remember that you sould inject the service in constructor-
this.searchService.searchSubject(subjectId)
 .then((subject)=> {
        if(subject && subject.length > 0){
            //code block;
        } else {
            //code block;
        }
    },
     (error)=>{
        //code block
     }
    )
```